# How do I get the logged user's information?

Tags: java, node.js, axios, jwt, vuejs3

I am developing a project for my school.
I would like to show a "My Profile" page for the user, so he/she can change his profile information (PUT Request) or even delete the account (DELETE Request).

I am using Typescript, Vue 3, nodejs and Axios for the Frontend.
Java, Spring boot security, JWT for the backend.

My question is:
How do I request the authenticated/signed in user's information and then "paint" it in a web.
One of my teachers told me to use this method in the backend. But it gives null and CORS doesn't allow Axios to complete the request.

```
 @GetMapping("/user/me")
    public String getMyUser(@CookieValue("jwtExample") String userToken) {
        return jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(userToken);
    }
```

```
const axiosApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://localhost:8080/api/auth`,
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
});

getMyUser(): Promise<AxiosResponse<string>> {
    return axiosApi.get("/user/me");
  }
```

This is the method where I try to read that response. Whenever I'm trying to use the response, the website breaks down. I'm kinda desperate haha

```
paintMyProfileInfo() {
      this.$store
        .dispatch("getMyData")
        .then((response) => (this.user = response.data))
        .catch((error: AxiosError) => console.log(error));
    },
```

I'm a bit lost.. and the website won't stop breaking down because of the elements I put in it (Vuetify elements) trying to "paint down" the response.

Comment: `CORS` - so make your server send CORS headers and you'll profit (it'll probably need to handle CORS preflight as well given you're setting cotnent-type

Comment: How do I do that? I have an annotation at the head of the controller```@CrossOrigins(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)```. Is this?

Comment: Ok. Now I have this object: ```myUser: {email: "",password: "",profile: {username: "",description: "",age: "",race: "",gender: "",province: "",picture: "",},roles: [],},  ``` I want this object to "get filled" with the response.data from a function to get the Token. It gets the token and the user (Works on Postman) but when I use the function on my frontend website it occurs Error 400. Bad Request.